# Как вывести все скидки всех магазинов, находящихся в торговом центре?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

В классе **Area** определена коллекция с **InformationContents** - это у нас скидки (или акции какие-то). Нужно написать LINQ запрос, который бы выводил все скидки (**InformationContents**) всех магазинов (**Area**), которые находятся в торговом центре (**Place**). Связь такая: **Place -> Floor -> Area**

Я еще писал запрос для вывода всех скидок определенного магазина (может это как-то поможет):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<InformationСontent>> GetAreaInformationContentToList(int areaId)
{
     // version 1
     var sales = await _unitOfWork.Context.Areas.Include(x => x.Floor)
                                                .ThenInclude(x => x.Place)
                                                .Where(x => x.Id == areaId)
                                                .SelectMany(x => x.InformationСontents)
                                                .Where(x => x.ActiveTo > DateTime.Now)
                                                .ToListAsync();
     return sales;

     //version 2
     //var sales = await _unitOfWork.Context.Areas.FromSqlRaw("").ToListAsync();
 }


public class Area
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
        public string WorkingTime { get; set; }

        public bool? IsLableShow { get; set; }
        public bool? IsLogoShow { get; set; }

        public int FloorId { get; set; }
        public Floor Floor { get; set; }

        public int? AreaCategoryId { get; set; }
        public AreaCategory AreaCategory { get; set; }

        public int? FileId { get; set; }
        public FileModel File { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AreaImage> AreaImages { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AreaPoint> AreaPoints { get; set; }

        public ICollection<InformationСontent> InformationСontents { get; set; }
    }


public class Floor : IHaveId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public int PlaceId { get; set; }
        public Place Place { get; set; }

        public int? FileId { get; set; }
        public FileModel File { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AreaPoint> AreaPoints { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }
        
    }



public class  Place : BaseEntity
    {
        //public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Adress { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]       
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string WebSiteURL { get; set; }
        public int? AreaInMeters { get; set; }
        public string WorkingTime { get; set; }

        public bool? IsLableShow { get; set; }
        public bool? IsLogoShow { get; set; }
        public bool ClockIsShowing { get; set; }
        public bool TickerIsShowing { get; set; }
        public string TickerText { get; set; }
        public bool WeatherIsShowing { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public int? FileId { get; set; }
        public FileModel File {get;set;}

        public ICollection<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
        public ICollection<StationMedia> StationMedias { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AreaCategoryType> AreaCategoryTypes { get; set; }
    }

public class InformationСontent : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int AreaId { get; set; } 
        public Area Area { get; set; }
        public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int FileId { get; set; }
        public FileModel File { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActiveFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActiveTo { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Ну вот вы написали код и что вы от него хотите. А в чём вопрос - ваш код не работает или работает не так, как ожидалось, выдаёт ошибку? Это тоже нужно всё написать в вопросе, иначе непонятно, в чём собственно вопрос.

Comment: @CrazyElf код, который я написал, выводит все скидки определенного магазина. А теперь мне нужно вывести все скидки всех магазинов

Comment: Убрать из запроса `.Where(x => x.Id == areaId)`?